# Woocommerce custom image product thumbnail in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hoping to get some help.

I currently have a woocommerce website, the ability to customise a product on woocommerce is limited, so I also have a third-party website for the custom products.

Customer will upload photo, customise their product and I want them to continue the checkout through main website.

Once customer adds custom product to their cart (in third party website) the URL used will direct them back to Woocommerce website.

i.e.
`?add-to-cart=product_id&attribute_reference=02&attribute_pricing=99`

What I need help with is the image.

It is currently using the standard woocommerce-placeholder.

How would I bring the customers custom product image across so that it is shown in the woocommerce checkout instead of the placeholder img.

Cheers!

Comment: code formatting

Comment: @Graipher thanks for that? Can you please elaborate for me?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write this in the field for the edit description, not the comment field.

Comment: Hi Shannon - did you find out how to do this?  I am trying to do the same thing at the moment...